# Existence of an inequality between probabilities of two events

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let $A,B$ be any two events such that $P(A\cap B)>0$ and $A$ is an event which depends on some variable $x$. Hence $P(A)$ is a function of $x$.

> I am trying to check if there exists a constant $C>0$ (which is independent of $x$) such that $P(A\cap B)\geq CP(A)$.

My attempt: It is a weird inequality because we know $P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)$. Also I think $P(A\cap B)>0$ implies that there exists a $C(x)$ such that $P(A\cap B)\geq C(x)P(A)$. But I don't think there exists an absolute constant $C$. On the other hand, both $P(A\cap B)$ and $P(A)$ depend on $x$ which gives me a feeling that $C$ need not depend on $x$. Any suggestions?

Comment: @geetha290krm But does $C=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$ depend on $x$ or does it not?

Comment: In general the answer is NO. You have mentioned very little about how the events depend on $x$, so the question cannot be answered.

Comment: @geetha290krm Is there an example of an event for which $C$ depends on $x$?

Comment: Very easy to construct such examples. Try intervals in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see how this is possible. The problem is asking us the value of C (where C between 0 and 1) such that C is independent of x. We can write:
$$
C\le\frac{P(A\cap{B})}{P(A)}
$$
For this to be independent of x, the numerator and denominator have to be proportional for each x. But I cannot see how this can be the case. Consider as an example an event A such that $P(A\cup{B})=1$ for every x (so trying to maximise the probability of A). Since we are trying to prove the problem for every A, it should apply to the above example as well. But:
$$
C\le\frac{P(A\cap{B})}{P(A)}\implies{C\le\frac{P(A\cap{B})}{P(A\cap{\lnot{B}})+P(A\cap{B})}}\implies{C\le\frac{P(A\cap{B})}{1-P(B)+P(A\cap{B})}}
$$
Since $P(B)$ doesn't depend on x, but $P(A\cap{B})$ does depend on x, the above fraction cannot have a constant value for every x. Also, since $P(A\cap{B})$ can be arbitrarily small, the above fraction has a limit towards zero.

Comment: I am not sure why $P(A\cap B^c) = 1 - P(B)$ in your example? For that to be true, $P(A\cap B^c) = P(B^c)$ should hold, and I don't see why that is the case?

Comment: That's because my example assumes that $P(A\cup{B})=1$. Ie. all outcomes are included in either A or B. I assumed this in order to maximise the probability of A, which is in the denominator (probability of B is constant).
$$P(A\cup{B})=1=P(A\cap{\lnot{B}})+P(B\cap{\lnot{A}})+P(B\cap{A})=P(A\cap{\lnot{B}})+P(B)
$$

Comment: To give an example: Let's say that our sample space is real numbers between [0,100], with continuous uniform distribution. B is the event: the number is between 0 and 10, and P(B)=1/10. A is the event: the number is between x and 100, where 0<x<10. As x approaches 10, the probability $P(A\cap{B})$ becomes smaller and smaller and the probability P(A) approaches 1-P(B)=9/10. It seems to me that the C parameter approaches zero, so I cannot see that it has some lower limit which is independent of x. Happy to be proven wrong!